# Deadlock among java card applets and can’t delete

Tags: applet, javacard

I have an environment where two applets share data with each other via shared interfaces, both holds the reference of each other.
**When I try to delete any of them I get 6985.**
It seems like a deadlock condition to me.
Can anyone suggest how can I flush them as I know keys.
P.S.
1. Auth with isd done successfully.
2. On delete command with p2=80

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to delete both applets in the same command? https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/guide/using-card-installer-deletion.htm#JCUGC308

Comment: I haven’t actually and yet I tried to see in GP2.2 and could not find any way to create an APDU for delete that can contain 2 delete packages. I will try and update you asap.

Comment: @Robert The mentioned link in above comment is for JAVA CARD 3, i have java card version 2.
I have tried to send the delete command with both applets package aid's but it doesn't work.
If you have any other leads do let me know.

Comment: The applets aren't using the same package, I suppose? Otherwise delete instances and then package *could* work. I haven't yet programmed myself in this particular corner though; usually I would use a separate library for these kind of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a deadlock, that you cannot solve to my knowledge, as I have created a similar situation.
The solution is to implement APDUs to dereference/release the sharedObjectInterfaces and run those before deleting or think about redesigning your data sharing approach into a a single SOI like a master/slave relation